# Remove character from awk result

Tags: awk

I'm running an awk command the prints out an output with a ":" in the result. How can I remove that? Is there a way to do the whole awk command in one?

The command I'm running is:

```
fdisk -l | '/Disk/{print $2
```

Which gives:

```
/dev/sda:
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
fdisk -l | awk -F'[ :]+' '/^Disk \// {print $2}' 
/dev/sda
```

Explanation:

`-F'[ :]+'` sets the field Separator to a space or colon, as long as there are more than one.

And I match `/^Disk \/`, to prevent some false positives (the forward slash needs to be escaped by a backslash).

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

For a list of all /dev/{disks} you can try using `lsblk` with the `-o {flags}`, and you don't need to be SU either... N.B. 'PATH' is a column header

```
lsblk -o PATH
```

That'll give you all disks and partitions (including loop partitions) as you'll see from "fdisk -l".

There's a lot more information that 'lsblk -o {flags}' will give you... Try this one for fun (and google/man for more)...

```
lsblk -o NAME,LABEL,PATH,MOUNTPOINT
```

Comment: Now, did you try typing that command? It's working just fine in Ubuntu right now...

OP asked to remove the ":"
"I'm running an awk command the prints out an output with a ":" in the result. How can I remove that?"

Could always grep and wildcard to get all /dev/sd partitions too...

lsblk -o PATH | grep "/dev/sd*"

Comment: Yes I did try that command. (`lsblk --version` returned `lsblk from util-linux 2.23.2`)

Comment: The column `PATH` is only added since [version 2.33](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.33/v2.33-ReleaseNotes). With older versions you can achieve the same using any of `lsblk -po KNAME` or `lsblk -po NAME`. If you don't want to list the partitions, it is `lsblk -pdo NAME` and if you want to get rid of the header `lsblk -pndo NAME`

Comment: Seems that util-linux 2.23 was released some time back in March 2013. Hopefully all these options can only but add value to anyone happening upon this post more recently :)

Comment: Unfortunately, a lot of companies cannot always use the latest version of a particular flavour of linux. They require some form of active support for which they require a non-free linux distribution and changing to a more modern version could require an expensive migration exercise which they try to avoid as often as possible.

Comment: Colour me confused., Was it worth sharing this option for those that may be beyond the 2.23.2 version that was released prior to the OP's original query? I'm kind of new to sharing here, so maybe I skipped  a beat? Can you possibly point me in the direction of how better to share responses? I mean, we've had two LTS releases since 2.23.2 according to this lnk... https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=util-linux
Please excuse my ignorance and I welcome any guidance...